# Size limit of input list parameter in a Rest Post Method

Tags: apexrest

What is the **size limit for the input parameter** in doPost method in below code ?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/insertcontact/*')

global with sharing class Mycontacts{

      @HttpPost
  global static List<Contact> doPost(List<Contact> lstcnts){
       insert lstcnts;
       return lstcnts;
      }

    }
```

Comment: My guess would be that the 10,000 row DML limit would be hit first (on the insert), though you might hit the 6M HTTP request limit or the 6M heap limit first instead. See [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm): I don't see any mention of other constraints in there but haven't looked closely...

Comment: @KeithC You're right, you can any size post so long as you don't break any governor limits.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox and Keith C for your answers. So ideally input list size must be less than 10,000. If I am wrong then please correct.

Comment: The list **must** be less than or equal to 10,000 records but you may hit other limits before that (depending on how many fields of the Contact are set). So best to be conservative and send a limited number at once e.g. 1,000.

Comment: Ok keith C, got the point. Thank You for clarification !!!!